# Scroll License NSIS not scrolling to end of License

Tags: nsis

I am using the [ScrollLicense Plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ScrollLicense_plug-in) with an attempt to force the user to scroll to the end of a License Agreement.

The problem I am hitting is they currently only have to scroll about 1/4th the way down the bar and it enables the "Next" button... has anyone run into this issue before?

Code is pretty straight forward and using everything from the plugin examples

LicenseForceSelection radiobuttons "I accept" "I decline"

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME 
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW LicenseShow
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "$(MUILicense)"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES

Function LicenseShow
 ScrollLicense::Set /NOUNLOAD /RADIOBUTTONS
FunctionEnd

Section -Main
Files here
Section End

Function .onGUIEnd
    ScrollLicense::Unload
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Could you post the license file or describe length, number of lines, number of empty lines? Asking because there are some sections in plugin code that refers to default number of License lines.